# MySQL server has gone away XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to insert some date from an `CSV` file from my computer.

I'm using `phpmyadmin`, `mysql`, `xamp`

I inserted this `csv` without an script. Only like this `IMPORT > CHOOSE FILE > I CHOOSE THE FORMAT TO CSV > GO`  . I don't change the specific format options.

I executed this operation and before this it gives me that error

> MySQL server has gone away

I google it, and i changed `innodb_log_file_size to 128M from 8M`, `max_allowed_packet to 128M from 8M` and i don't know if it had to be changed `innodb_lock_wait_timeout to 6000 from 50`

[This is my `CSV`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rAHNgovOUv3Qiko0pOzsg9BvgFtl5d0f/view?usp=sharing)

[IMAGE 1 - import csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/honif.jpg)

[IMAGE 2 - the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L68uh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when the mysql server decides to close the connection, crashes, or hangs. This looks like a large dataset so its possible mysql is closing the connection prematurely while the data is being prepared.

try changing the `wait_timeout` parameter https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Comment: may be a silly question, but are you restarting your mysql server every time you're making configuration changes?

Comment: yes.. i saw the problem.. when i was making the changes.. he do not save what 
i were writing in the file. (don't know why..)
But.. I solved..finally :)
Thank you for your time :)..